# HTTP Failure in Axios TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduxSourceAction' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

How to get redux source action type in axios middlware in success?

Current axios-middleware is not supporting this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

> "axios": "0.18.0",

This version works fine. Thanks to my colleagues to help me out.